# Fubini/Tonelli theorems for expectation of power series

Tags: pr.probability, analytic-functions

as part of a proof in a paper i have statement, i cannot figure out how to proof:

*Assume $(c_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of nonnegative random variables and $g: (-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that

$f(x,\omega):= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k(\omega)x^k$

$\mathbb{E}(f(x,\cdot) \leq g(x)$

for  all $x\in (-1,1]$.

Then

$\mathbb{E}(f(x,\cdot)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}(c_k)(\omega)x^k $

for all $x\in (-1,1]$*.

The only explanation in the paper is *...apply Fubinin's theorem...*, but i can't find one which can be applied here.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\ge0$, [Fubini-Tonelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_function) and for $x<0$, [Fubini-Lebesgue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#For_integrable_functions).

Comment: Thanks. I solved it now with monotone convergence (for $x \geq 0 $ ) theorem and dominated convergence theorem ($ x < 0$).